# Symfony/Doctrine: How to iterate through table fields for hydration?

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

After making a SQL query to **Table Post** I wish to hydrate the $result array to a Doctrine object. Right now in order to do this I use a **set** command for each field, as below:

```
 
    $post = new post();
    $post->setCategory($result['category']);
    $post->setName($result['name']);
    $post->setRating($result['rating']);
```

My question is is there a better way to do this, such as iterating through all the table fields? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fromArray()`:

```
$post = new Post();
$post->fromArray($results);
```

Comment: You cannot call the constructor like that, just checked in doctrine's source (see the class Doctrine_Record).

Comment: My bad, I'd mistaken it for sfForms in symfony.

Comment: Np, I've just added it for the record. Can you please remove that part from your answer?

Comment: Done. I was going to earlier, but I felt weird editing an answer that had been accepted.